# Use directory function in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, file

I want to compare filenames in folder "video/test" with entries in table "files" column "filename". I have tried using "dir()" to fetch the array and implode it in the my mysql query. but it's not right as a get invalid argument warning. is there a better way of doing this?

```
$filenames = dir("video/test");
$sql = sprintf( 'SELECT * FROM files WHERE filename not in ("%s")', implode( '","', $filenames ) );
$sql = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['filename'];  
}
```

Comment: change implode( '","', $filenames ) to '"'.implode( '","', $filenames ).'"' it better also to use mysql_real_escape_string for each array value

Comment: @Akam He already has the outside quote marks in the format string `...not in ("%s")`

Comment: I agree, will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
$filenames = scandir('video/test');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Not this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php